# Cordova Android 4.3 Ajax Status 404

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am writing an Android app using `Cordova 3.4.0`.

In the app I make the following ajax request using jquery...

```
$.ajax ({
  url: 'http://www.[mydomain].com/api/v1',
  type: 'GET',
  username: id,
  password: pwd,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true 
  },
})
.done (function (response) {
   doSomethng();
})
.fail (function (response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

On `Android 4.4.x` the request works as expected, however on `Android 4.3` (both emulator and device) it fails and the following is logged to the console...

```
readystate: 4
status: 404
statusText: "error"
```

I have `<access origin="*" />` in the `config.xml` and

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

in the AndroidManifest.xml. I can also confirm that the request is not making it to my web service and nothing is logged on that end.

I am at a loss as to what might be blocking the request.  I know that the WebView component is different in `4.4.x` than in previous versions but I am not sure if that has anything to do with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ask you webservice developer to, is there set any header or not

Comment: There is no header set.  I have also just confirmed that I am seeing the same behavior on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. For anyone running into the same issue do this...

Replace

```
$.ajax ({
url: 'http://www.[mydomain].com/api/v1',
type: 'GET',
username: id,
password: pwd,
xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: true 
}
})
```

with

```
$.ajax ({
url: 'http://www.messagefund.com/webresources/v1',
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(id + ':' + pwd));  
},
type: 'GET'
})
```

Confirmed that this works in iOS 6.1/7.0/7.1, Android 4.3.x, 4.4.x and Windows Phone 8.